# Is there an inexpensive way to get started with GAL (Generic Array Logic) chips?

Tags: programmable-logic

GAL chips seem expensive to get started with, since programmers cost hundreds of dollars and even ISP cables aren't cheap.

Is there a cheaper way?

Comment: I've always heard it rendered as "Gate Array Logic". "Generic Array Logic" Is new to me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_array_logic That's what they always called them in my EE classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not even sure GALs are still around today. CPLDs and FPGAs are preferred I believe, though I'm no expert.  You can dig up development kits from digilentinc.com.  There's a CPLD kit for $18 and the USB JTAG programming cable is $50.  Those parts are Digilent C-Mod and JTAG-USB Cable.  I believe the software (at least starter software) is free.  Good luck!

Comment: I just think it's a bit ridiculous that the programmers are more than twice as much as the kit itself.

Comment: Chips are cheap.  Well, cables ought to be cheap, but there is a bit of intelligence in the cable. And it's proprietary.  So yeah, it is a little ridiculous.

Comment: If chips are cheap, use a cpld to make a cpld programmer... posted as a joke, but that's actually what you will find inside a lot of them.  Often the USB ones are an FT245 and the same CPLD previously used in the parallel version.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.leonheller.com/XC9536/XC9536.pdf) is the schematic for a simple home-made PCB for experimenting with Xilinx XC9536 CPLDs. It has a connector for a Xilinx programming cable, a socket for a crystal oscillator and an LED, as well as a small prototyping area. The artwork file is available.

Answer (score 4):

Standard GALs need funky voltages and waveforms for programming. Lattice do some 'ispGAL' products which added an IS interface, but unless you want to stick to DILs and/or 5V, low-end CPLDs are more capable and easier to program.

Answer (score 3):

A simple GAL programmer: http://elm-chan.org/works/pgal/report_e.html

And if you want to know how to program: http://www.rexfisher.com/Downloads/CUPL%20Tutorial.htm

Comment: 2nd link defunct (but it's four years on so fair enough)